# Is there an algorithm to find the nearest number with only small factors?

Tags: algorithm, factoring

I need to do some real time DFT and the algorithm I am using is the most efficient when the number of samples can be broken down into small factors.

Suppose that I have a number `n` and factors `2, 3, 5`. How to find the nearest number (compared to `n`) whose prime factorisation consists of no numbers other than `2,3,5`?

`n` is almost always below `50,000` so brute forcing might be a good idea.

Comment: That sounds more like a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You may use something sieve like approach.

Comment: How large is `n` typically? If it is restricted to 32 bits, the most efficient solution could be to precompute all candidate numbers, store them in an array and just do a binary search.

Comment: Would you be interested in a neat, fast algorithm to find the nearest greater number that has only 2 factors (say, 2 and 3)?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I think that would work

Comment: Because of your range, you _could_ pre-compute all possible values and then do a binary search on the table for each sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A fast algorithm for pairs of factors

This doesn't quite solve the problem as stated -- given some integer x, it will only find the nearest greater-or-equal number that has no factors besides 2 and 3 (or any other given *pair* of factors).  But I think it's cute and since it runs in O(log x) time and O(1) space it might be useful regardless!  It's similar in concept to the Bresenham line algorithm.  In pseudocode:

1. Start with b = y = 2^RoundUp(log2(x)), which ensures that b = y >= x.
2. If y < x then set y = y * 3 and go to 2.
3. If y < b then set b = y.  (b records the best candidate so far.)
4. If y is odd then stop and return b.
5. Otherwise, set y = y / 2 and go to 2.

### Correctness

Why does this work?  Notice that at all times, we have y = 2^i*3^j for some i, j >= 0, and that over time, i only ever decreases, while j only ever increases.  The invariant we maintain on entry to step 2 is **"Any value z = 2^a*3^b having a > i or b < j is known to be uninteresting** (i.e., invalid or no better than some already-discovered solution), **and so doesn't need to be considered"**.  This is clearly true the first time we arrive at step 2, since y is a power of 2 and already >= x, so any number z = 2^a*3^b with a > i would then be at least 2*y (regardless of b) which is worse than y; and no integer z can have fewer than the j = 0 powers of 3 in y.

(Another way to state this invariant is "Either we have already found the optimal solution, or it is some number z = 2^a*3^b with a <= i and b >= j.")

If the condition at step 2, "y < x", is satisfied, then y = 2^i*3^j is not a valid solution as it's too low.  More strongly, it's clear that for any a <= i, 2^a*3^j cannot be a valid solution either, as any such solution is at least as low as y.  So now we know (from the invariant) that any pair (a, b) satisfying (a > i OR b < j) is uninteresting, and we know from the "y < x" test that just succeeded that any pair (a, b) satisfying (a <= i AND b = j) is uninteresting too.  Now consider any pair (a, b) satisfying the slightly different condition (a > i OR b < j+1): if (a, b) doesn't satisfy the first condition (from the invariant) for uninterestingness then we have ((a > i OR b < j+1) AND !(a > i OR b < j)), which simplifies to ((a > i OR b < j+1) AND (a <= i AND b >= j)) via De Morgan's rule, and then to (b < j+1 AND a <= i AND b >= j) (because making (a <= i AND b >= j) true requires (a <= i) to be true, forcing (a > i) to be false and thus allowing its elimination from the OR), which is clearly the same as (a <= i AND b = j) -- but that is exactly the condition for which we have just established a second kind of uninterestingness, via the success of the "y < x" test.  So this establishes that any pair (a, b) satisfying (a > i OR b < j+1) is uninteresting -- which, after incrementing j, becomes exactly the invariant we want to preserve.

The justification for decrementing i in step 5 is almost the same, but in reverse, so I won't go into detail on it.  The slight difference is that if we get to step 5, instead of having an *invalid* solution, we simply have a solution that is at least as high as the best solution in b (notice that we updated b if necessary so that this would continue to hold), and so it and every higher solution is (from this point on) uninteresting to us.

Each value of y generated by the algorithm either has one less factor of 2 or one more factor of 3 than any previously generated value, so it's clear that all generated y values are distinct.  The reasoning in the earlier paragraphs establishes that the only y values *not* generated are those that have been proven to be uninteresting.  Thus if the algorithm always halts in a finite time, it is correct.  The next section will imply that this is indeed the case.

### Running time

Step 5 (which has the effect of decreasing i by 1) never executes more than log2(x)+1 times, since i starts at this value or less, nothing else affects i, and when i reaches 0, y will be odd, causing step 4 to terminate the function.  But how many times can the condition in step 2 that increases j by 1 fire?

Initially y >= x, so achieving the y < x condition needed for step 2 to fire requires an execution of step 5.  But as soon as y < x is achieved by some execution of step 5, it is immediately undone at the next execution of step 2: this is because in order for step 5 to execute at all, we must have had y >= x, and if we divide y by 2 (at that step 5) and then multiply it by 3 (at the next step 2), it will necessarily be at least as large as it was previously, implying y >= x again, in turn implying that *step 2 will never fire twice in a row without an execution of step 5 in between*.  So step 2 will fire at most as many times as step 5 does, i.e. at most log2(x)+1 times.  This bounds the overall runtime of the algorithm at O(log x).

### Notes

- You can avoid floating-point arithmetic by replacing the log2() in step 1 with a loop that starts y at 1 and keeps doubling it until it is >= x.  This is O(log x) and so doesn't hurt the time complexity.
- You can use any other pair of factors.  The only real change is that, if f is the factor "replacing" 2 in the code, then step 4 should instead halt when y % f != 0.

Comment: Regarding note 1: on some CPU architectures there are special instructions to do this in O(1). GCC offers a set of builtins `__builtin_clz{,l,ll}` to do this in a CPU-independent way.

Answer (score 4):

There are exactly 265 numbers that are divisible only by 2,3,5 in the range 1 to 50000. So  you could make a small table, and look up the answer in the table. However, on my computer, it takes an average of 6.5 microseconds to find the nearest 2-3-5-factorable number for a given number, so I'd say brute force is good enough.

```
int isValid( int n )
{
    while ( n%2 == 0 )
        n /= 2;
    while ( n%3 == 0 )
        n /= 3;
    while ( n%5 == 0 )
        n /= 5;

    return n == 1;
}

int findBest( int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( isValid(n+i) )
            return n+i;
        if ( isValid(n-i) )
            return n-i;
    }
    return 0;   // should never get here
}

int main( void )
{
    for ( int n = 1; n <= 50000; n++ )
        printf( "%d->%d\n", n,findBest(n) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is any efficient solution to this.Below is the brute force approach for finding the closest number to n.

```java
    int diff=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int num=0;
    public void closestNumber(int n,int curr)
    {
        if(diff < Math.abs(n -curr) && curr  >= n)
        return;
        if(diff >= Math.abs(n -curr))
        {
            diff = Math.abs(n -curr);
            num=curr;
        }
        closestNumber(n,curr*2);
        closestNumber(n,curr*3);
        closestNumber(n,curr*5);

    }


closestNumber(n,1);

System.out.println("closest number: "+num);
```

Comment: `sum` has no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

The code below finds the closest number to a target that is divisible by *at least one* number in a given set of factors. It does not provide a solution to the clarified goal, to find the nearest number that is divisible *only* by a given set of factors.

**Original:**

The series of numbers divisible by 2, 3, or 5 is [OEIS A080671](https://oeis.org/A080671) and has a simple recursive formula a(n+22) = a(n)+30. In addition, the series conveniently has only single-integer gaps. This means you can simply determine whether your number lies on one of these gaps and select either the next or previous integer.

```
class NumberFinder
{
public:
    NumberFinder()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * 3 * 5; i++)
        {
            bool hasSmallFactors =
                (i % 2 == 0) ||
                (i % 3 == 0) ||
                (i % 5 == 0);
            series.push_back(hasSmallFactors);
        }
    }

    int Find(int n)
    {
        int x = n % (2 * 3 * 5);
        if (series[x]) return n; // already good
        return n + 1; // guaranteed to be good
    }

private:
    vector<bool> series;
};
```

This can also be generalized to any set of desired factors:

```
class NumberFinder
{
public:
    NumberFinder(vector<int> factors)
    {
        product = 1;
        for (auto factor : factors) product *= factor;
        for (int i = 0; i < product; i++)
        {
            bool hasSmallFactors = false;
            for (auto factor : factors)
            {
                if (i % factor == 0) hasSmallFactors = true;
            }
            series.push_back(hasSmallFactors);
        }
    }

    int Find(int n)
    {
        int lo = n;
        int hi = n;
        bool found = series[n % product];
        while (!found)
        {
            if (--lo < 0) lo = 0;
            hi++;
            found = series[hi % product] || series[lo % product];
        }
        if (series[lo % product]) return lo;
        return hi;
    }

private:
    int product;
    vector<bool> series;
};
```

Comment: I am trying to find numbers that are only divisible by `2,3,5` and their products. OEIS A080671 contains numbers such as 21 that don't satisfy this criterion

Comment: @HenryW. That is a significantly simpler problem. If your number must be divisible by 2 AND 3 AND 5, you simply need to find the closest match to a multiple of 2*3*5 = 30, i.e. `((n+15)/30)*30`, or more generally, `((n+(p/2))/p)*p)` where `p` is the product of your target factors.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the resulting number's prime factorisation cannot have any number other than `2,3,5`

Comment: @HenryW. Ah, that's a significantly more *difficult* problem (finding the closest [Hamming number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number)), and cannot be solved using a periodic series as shown above.